# QGIS layer filter doesn't work if there is an other condition next to a regexp one

Tags: qgis, filter, regular-expression

I have layer in qgis. It has an attribute `data_count (Integer)` and a `value (String)`.

When I filer for  `"value" ~ 'maximum-speed-limit'` it works. When I filter for `"data_count" > 10` it works as well.
But when I use `"data_count" > 5 AND "value" ~ 'maximum-speed-limit'` it says error:

```
An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said:
OGR[3] error 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting end of string. Occurred around :
"data_count" > 5 AND "value" ~ 'maximum-speed-limit'
```

But if I don't use regexp, but use `LIKE` instead, it works perfectly : `"data_count" > 5 AND "value" LIKE '%maximum-speed-limit%'`

Why is that happening? I tried and see that other "more complicated" regexp expressions don't work either, like `"value" ~'[0-9].*`. But then why the simple `"somevalue"~'sometext'` works? I have read the QGIS documentation but the answer is not clear to me.

Comment: Where are you applying this expression, in which dialog?

Comment: If this is the Layer Filter dialog, please also specify which filetype/datasource your layer is in (shp, gpkg, postgres etc.). I believe `~` is not supported in Layer Filter for OGR layers, (defaults to SQLite which does not support `~` unlike Postgres). Can you confirm that when you say `"value" ~ 'maximum-speed-limit'` works, it actually filters the results correctly, rather than just not throwing up an error message? Because with gpkg and a simple `~` expression, if I press Test it shows an error, but if I press OK it silently lets me through - however there are no filtered results.

Comment: It is an imported GeoJSON and I used it in the Layer Filter dialog. 
I am quite sure that I pressed "Test" and "Ok" as well and it worked, but today I cannot reproduce it. So I will just delete my question. Thanks for the answer!